# XML Generation and output of it Using PLSQL

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, oracle11g, xml-parsing

Below XML which need to be generated .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Form1>
<ContentForm>
<SectionI>
<Date>13/01/2023</Date>
</SectionI>
<SectionII>
<Type>C</Type>
<ID>1809</ID>
<RIC></RIC>
<UEN>019</UEN>
<Name>Limited</Name>
</SectionII>
</ContentForm>
</Form1>
```

1. Is xmlconcat correct to combine different section or is there any
   other approach
2. How to generated first xml version tag and concat it in main xml?
3. can we put it in OUT variable of PLSQL if yes how to do it
4. how to open Form And ContentForm tag in the query .

Oracle Query

```
SELECT
    xmlconcat
    (   
        XMLELEMENT
        ("SectionI",XMLELEMENT("Date",SYSDATE)
        )
    ,
        XMLELEMENT
        ("SectionII",
            XMLELEMENT("Type",'C'),
            XMLELEMENT("ID",'1809'),
            XMLELEMENT("RIC",NULL),
            XMLELEMENT("UEN",'019'),
            XMLELEMENT("Name",'Limited')
        ) 
    )
    from dual
```

```
Select 
XMLELEMENT("?xml",xmlattributes('1.0' as  "Version",'UTF-8' as  "encoding",'no' as  "standalone"))
from dual
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use special xml functions than string functions. You can do that using xmlroot and 2 more `xmlelement`:

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/if0oBYgF

```sql
select
    xmlroot(
          XMLELEMENT("Form1",
             XMLELEMENT("ContentForm",
                XMLELEMENT("SectionI",XMLELEMENT("Date",SYSDATE))
               ,XMLELEMENT("SectionII",
                  XMLELEMENT("Type",'C'),
                  XMLELEMENT("ID",'1809'),
                  XMLELEMENT("RIC",NULL),
                  XMLELEMENT("UEN",'019'),
                  XMLELEMENT("Name",'Limited')
               ) 
             )
          )
        ,VERSION '1.0'
        ,STANDALONE NO
       )
    as xdata
from dual;
```

Result:

```
XDATA
------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<Form1>
  <ContentForm>
    <SectionI>
      <Date>2023-06-06</Date>
    </SectionI>
    <SectionII>
      <Type>C</Type>
      <ID>1809</ID>
      <RIC/>
      <UEN>019</UEN>
      <Name>Limited</Name>
    </SectionII>
  </ContentForm>
</Form1>
```

Comment: How to put encoding in xml tag ?  Also ric tag is directly closed , We want it open and close as seperate tag

Comment: It worked by giving this in  for encoding -> VERSION '1.0" encoding="UTF-8'

Comment: @sharanjain note that "encoding=UTF-8" is valid only if you use xmlserialize to blob, otherwise your encoding depends on your client NLS settings. Example with encoding: https://dbfiddle.uk/OkqFEaVp

Comment: and regarding `<ric/>`, it's full equivalent of `<ric></ric>`  in xml, so it doesn't matter how it's written.

Comment: While storing the output in clob column and retrieving it , we are getting /n Character . How to avoid this ?